# Preserving Pandas timestamp type in a Pyspark dataframe

Tags: hive, pyspark

I am writing the contents of a `Pandas` dataframe, `t`, to a Hive table in `Pyspark`.

The `t` has one column `Request_time_local` of type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`:

```
In: print t.loc[0,'Request_time_local']
Out: 2016-12-09 13:01:27
```

The Hive  table has a column `request_time_local` of type `timestamp`:

```
col_name              | data_type
request_time_local    | timestamp
```

I convert `t` to a `Pyspark dataframe` for writing to Hive:

```
t_rdd = spark.createDataFrame(t)
t_rdd.registerTempTable("temp_result")
```

The `request_time_local` column is not populated in my table, but all others are.

On conversion to `Pyspark dataframe`, `request_time_local` is a `bigint` unix timestamp:

```
spark.createDataFrame(t)
DataFrame[request_time_local: bigint, ...]
```

I check this by converting the `Pyspark dataframe` back to pandas.

```
t_check = t_rdd.toPandas()
In: print t_check.loc[0,'Request_time_local']
Out: 1481288487000000000
```

I'm wondering:

1) Is `request_time_local` failing to populate because I am writing `bigint` from the `Pyspark dataframe` to `timestamp` in the Hive table column?

2) Is there a way to preserve `timestamp` type in the `Pyspark dataframe` for compatibility with the Hive table column type?

(I realize one solution here is to change Hive column to `int` and write the unix timestamp.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

spark.createDataFrame(t) \
  .withColumn("parsed", (col("Request_time_local") / 1000**3).cast("timestamp"))
```